# Meteor.setTimeout doesn't return handle server-side

Tags: meteor

(Meteor.js library  v1.x)

When I can call Meteor.setTimeout() client side it does what I expect and returns a handle (essentially a number) which I can later use to clearTimeout etc. - when I call Meteor.setTimeout() server-side what is returned is an object that looks like this:

```
 { _idleTimeout: 1,
  _idlePrev: 
     { _idleNext: [Circular],
       _idlePrev: [Circular],
       msecs: 1,
   ontimeout: [Function: listOnTimeout] },
  _idleNext: 
    { _idleNext: [Circular],
      _idlePrev: [Circular],
      msecs: 1,
      ontimeout: [Function: listOnTimeout] },
      _idleStart: 1416549645303,
      _onTimeout: [Function],
      _repeat: false }
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested in a regular node.js REPL, and that's what `setTimeout` returns. Passing it to `Meteor.clearTimeout` should work fine. The only problem is the documentation, which incorrectly states that the arguments to `Meteor.clearTimeout` and `Meteor.clearInterval` have type `Number`, whereas it only has that type on the client.